# C Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I can't find the seg fault in the following code and I'm hoping someone can point it out for me.

I have a singly linked list of the following structs whose id's are consecutive starting from 0:

```
typedef struct basic_block_struct
{
    int id;
    bit_vector *dominators;
    struct basic_block_struct *next;
} basic_block;
```

Later, when the list needs to be searched a lot I try to use an array of pointers to each block in the list to take advantage of indexing.  There should be a one to one correspondence between the id's of the blocks and the indices of the array:

```
basic_block **dom_array = (basic_block **)malloc(num_bb * sizeof(basic_block *));

basic_block *search_bb;
search_bb = head; //The head of the list of blocks

while (search_bb != NULL)
{
    dom_array[search_bb->id] = &*search_bb; //Not sure the &* is needed
    search_bb = search_bb->next;
}

set_bit(dom_array[0]->dominators, 0, TRUE);
```

It is definitely the last line that is causing the seg fault.  The function call is legal -- it just sets the first bit (bit 0) of the bit_vector "dominators" in the first block -- but it appears it is not pointing to a basic_block.

Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: There's not enough context with your question to answer with any certainty. It may be that you never hit a case where search_bb->id == 0 in your loop and thus dom_array[0] remains unitialized. Or it could be that 'dominators' is not a valid address. In any case, a good memory debugger would go a long way. If you happen to be on Linux, check out http://valgrind.org/. You won't regret learning how to use it.

Comment: &* is not needed, does it fail without it?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get a segmentation fault and can't see the answer in less than a minute, use valgrind. Here is a [valgrind tutorial that shows what it can do](http://cs.ecs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/valgrind/). Object oriented programmers use unit tests every time they change their code. C programmers should use valgrind the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, mystery solved.  I outsmarted myself.  That bit_vector never gets allocated. :-(